# Is it possible to deploy Dapp on Ethereum classic network and be listed in mist?

Tags: dapps, ethereum-classic

So as a small bisness entety can not pay 100k USD for app deployment, one wonders on is it possible to deploy Dapp not in the test net but in a more real ETC one?

Comment: Why do you think it costs 100k to deploy a contract? The block gas limit is ~4mil which is ~0.08 ETH at current gas prices. This seems manageable to any company